# PostgreSQL INSERT INTO production table FROM staging table

Tags: postgresql

I created two tables using Django models and the scripts look something like this

I am using PostgreSQL 10

production table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.foods_food(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('foods_food_id_seq'::regclass),
    code character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    product_name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    brands character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    quantity character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    last_modified_datetime timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
)
```

staging table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.foods_temp(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('foods_temp_id_seq'::regclass),
    code character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    product_name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
)
```

I copied a CSV file to the staging table and than I tried to copy the columns from the staging table to the production table using the following query.

```
INSERT INTO foods_food
   SELECT * FROM foods_temp;
```

But I got this error.

```
ERROR:  null value in column "created_at" violates not-null constraint
```

I can set the `created_at` column to accept null in order to make it work but I want the `created_at` values to be auto populated when entries are inserted.

Is there other way to copy columns to the production table and automatically insert the timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you need to set default values:

```
ALTER TABLE public.foods_food ALTER last_modified_datetime
   SET DEFAULT current_timestamp;
ALTER TABLE public.foods_food ALTER created_at
   SET DEFAULT current_timestamp;
```